# Minimizing the iterative sum of pairs of numbers in a list

Tags: algorithms, lists, subset-sum

Given the tuple (list, value):

$$\left(\left[x_1, x_2, \cdots x_n\right], y\right)$$

You may choose two adjacent values in the list to modify the tuple as:

$$\left(\left[x_1, x_2, \cdots x_{i-1}, (x_i + x_{i+1}), x_{i+2} \cdots x_n\right], y + x_{i} + x_{i+1}\right)$$

Iterate until:

$$\left(\left[\sum_i x_i\right], y + z\right)$$

What is the optimal set of choices that minimizes $z$?

Intuitively, you never want to operate on the largest number in the list.  But the largest number in this list changes as you add values together.  In other words, the optimal solution is not necessarily obtained by an optimal solution of a sub-problem.

A greedy solution would start by taking the smallest number in this list and adding it to the smaller of its adjacent numbers.  This solution, while close, is not equivalent to the value returned by brute force search.  This points to the fact the some locally optimal step is not globally optimal, which could be connected to the fact that the largest element of the list changes as values are added together.

Comment: Do you mean the product of $x_{i+2},\ldots,x_n$ by $x_{i+2}\cdots x_n$?

Comment: What does the modification do if the value is not zero?  Does it add $x_i+x_{i+1}$ to the value?  Can you [edit] the question to specify that?

Comment: Have you tried using dynamic programming?  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info for some guidance on applying it.  Where did you encounter this problem?  Can you [edit] the question to state where you encountered it and provide a source if you saw it somewhere?

Comment: Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: Dynamic programming doesn't work since the subproblems change. You could hash the list, but it still doesn't break down nicely.

Comment: There is no source for this problem other than it being a subproblems to optimally composing functions with linear complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that initially $y=0$, as this makes no difference in your problem.

Look at the very last two elements $a,b$ that you will apply your operation on:
The tuple is $([a,b], y$) and, at the next iteration, it will necessarily be $([a+b], $y+a+b$)$, since $a+b = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ is a constant, you only want to minimize $y$.

Notice that $a$  (resp. $b$) must have been obtained as a sum of some **contiguous** sequence of elements of your list starting from $x_1$ (resp. ending in $x_n$).

Calling $OPT[i,j]$ the minimum value of $y+z=z$ in your problem when the input instance consists of $([x_1, \dots, x_j], 0)$, we then obtain (for $n > 1$):

$$
OPT[1,n] = \sum_{h=1}^n x_h + min_{h=1,\dots,n-1}  \left\{ OPT[1,h] + OPT[h+1,n] \right\}
$$

and, in general:

$$
OPT[i,j] = 
\begin{cases}
\sum_{h=i}^j x_h + min_{h=i,\dots,j-1}  \left\{ OPT[i,h] + OPT[h+1,j] \right\} & \mbox{if } j-i>0 \\
0 & \mbox{if } j-i = 0
\end{cases}.
$$

There are $O(n^2)$ subproblems and each requires taking a minimum over $O(n)$ elements, so your problem can be solved in $O(n^3)$ time via dynamic programming.

Comment: Should it not be $OPT[i,h-1] + OPT[h,j]$?

Comment: Fixed :) It is $OPT[i,h] + OPT[h+1,j]$ since $h$ ranges from $1$ to $j-1$.

Comment: Great answer!  I couldn't get that first assumption correct.  But it is now painfully obvious.  I am curious how well this solution works if the "addition" is approximate.  I am trying to use this to optimize a foldl operation with approximate linear complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is known as [optimal alphabetic binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding#Optimal_alphabetic_binary_trees_(Hu%E2%80%93Tucker_coding)) (or various similar names). This is an ordered version of Huffman coding, in which the two numbers being added don't have to be adjacent. The problem can be solved in $O(n\log n)$ using either the Hu–Tucker algorithm or the [Garsia–Wachs algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garsia%E2%80%93Wachs_algorithm).